# Which are the features of C++0x that will remain for sure (if any)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, language-features

Are there any features of C++0x that are known to be there for sure?
Like, maybe, threads in the standard library?

Answer (score 7):

Actually none. At any point up to the publication of the standard, ISO can change it, since it's subject to the vagaries of the voting process.

In reality, any major feature that's currently in the draft will remain (although tweaking is possible). They've already stated that they'll miss their 2009 delivery and ISO is as political a beast as any country, so they'll not want to miss another one.

So while you won't see tuples or threads or other major library changes being removed, there could be minor variations, nothing that will have a major impact on delivery of the standard (and hopefully, timely implementation by the vendors).

Comment: The latest draft is at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2857.pdf.  It is very unlikely at this point that there will be any substantive changes; for one thing, vendors are busy implementing a lot of this.

Answer (score 2):

- New string literals
- `auto` type deduction
- Template typedefs
- R-value references

to name a few and most of TR1.

Take a look at the [C++0x Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#) article -- but it is best to check with your compiler vendor to know ***what you can use***.